# Formula help for calculation

Tags: formula, currency

Need some help editing a formula to calculate commissions. This is the full scenario written out (numbers are changed) and my current formula below that needs some additions (and is not working):

If a deal is Closed Won,
Type ISPICKVAL "New Business" or "Existing Business",
If Opp ACV <= 1700 and User Role is "VP Sales", then it's Opp ACV x 0.01,
If Opp ACV >1700, User Role is "VP Sales", then it's Opp ACV x 0.02,
Also, if Channel Partner ISPICKVAL "Partner", then it's (Opp ACV x 40%)x 0.05 -- getting credit for 40% of the ACV, and taking 5% of that

If Opp ACV <= 1000, User Role is "Sales Director", then it's Opp ACV x 0.03
If Opp ACV > 1000, User Role is "Sales Director", then it's Opp ACV x 0.04
Also, if Channel Partner ISPICKVAL "Partner", then it's (Opp ACV x 40%)x 0.05 -- getting credit for 40% of the ACV, and taking 5% of that

Additionally,
If Type ISPICKVAL "Renewal" and User Role is "VP Sales" or "Sales Director",
then it's Renewal_Increase_field__c x 0.06,
but if User Role is "CSM" and Parent_Opp_CARR__c < = 5000, then it's Opp ACV x 0.07, if Parent_Opp_CARR_c > 5000, then it's Opp ACV x 0.08

Here is what I currently have. Please help (and if it can be simplified, too):

```
IF(
    AND(IsWon, CASE(Type,"New Business", 1, "Existing Business", 1, 0) = 1),
    IF(AND(Opp_ACV__c <= 1700, Owner.UserRole.Name="VP Sales"),
        Opp_ACV__c * 0.01
        IF(AND(Opp_ACV__c > 1700, Owner.UserRole.Name = "VP Sales"),
            Opp_ACV__c*0.02,
            IF(
                OR(
                    TEXT(Channel_Partner__c) = "Partner",
                    AND(Opp_ACV__c <= 1700, Owner.UserRole.Name="VP Sales")
                ),
                (Opp_ACV__c * 0.40) * 0.05,
                IF(
                    OR(
                        TEXT(Channel_Partner__c) = "Partner",
                        AND(Opp_ACV__c > 1700, Owner.UserRole.Name = "VP Sales")
                    ),
                    (Opp_ACV__c * 0.40) * 0.01,
                    IF(
                        AND(Opp_ACV__c <= 1000, Owner.UserRole.Name = "Sales Director"),
                        Opp_ACV__c * 0.03,
                        IF(
                            AND(Opp_ACV__c > 1000, Owner.UserRole.Name = "Sales Director"),
                            Opp_ACV__c * 0.04,
                            IF(
                                OR(
                                    TEXT(Channel_Partner__c) = "Partner",
                                    AND(Opp_ACV__c <= 1000, Owner.UserRole.Name="Sales Director")
                                ),
                                (Opp_ACV__c * 0.40) * 0.03,
                                IF(
                                    OR(
                                        TEXT(Channel_Partner__c) = "Partner",
                                        AND(Opp_ACV__c > 1000000, Owner.UserRole.Name = "Sales Director")
                                    ),
                                    (Opp_ACV__c * 0.40) * 0.04,
                                    0
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
),
IF(
    ISPICKVAL(Type,"Renewal"), 
    CASE(Owner.UserRole.Name, "VP Sales", 1, "Sales Director", 1, 0) = 1,
    Renewal_Increase__c* 0.06,
    IF(
        Owner.UserRole.Name = "CSM",
        IF(
            Parent_Opportunity__r.Opp_LT_CARR__c <= 50000,
            Opp_ACV__c * 0.05, 
            Opp_ACV__c * 0.04
        ),
        0
    )
),
0
)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. You appear to be missing the outer-most part of the formula in your posting of your existing definition (the IF has a sibling IF). Could you perhaps edit it to add the missing detail? Also, it would help a lot if you indented the formula details to make it easier to follow the structure.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE!  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to include details about what is not working, especially the data values, what values you expect to get, and what values you are seeing instead.  Also -- when troubleshooting a complex formula that covers multiple areas, one approach is to simplify the formula down to just one area, make sure that works, then add the next area and test until you've found the problematic section.

Comment: Note that Derek F's reformatting has revealed how this formula is incorrectly structured.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of re-formatting the formula you provided (in the hopes that it makes it easier for others to parse). There's so many nested `IF` there that it makes lines run long, but when you're working with more than 2 levels of parenthesis or so, I find it much easier to make sure everything is at the right level and that all of the parens are closed when you ruthlessly apply indentation.

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting an error of: Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'